# qgis2threejs and large area

Tags: dem, orthophoto, qgis2threejs

In my project I am trying to create a model of a large territory (10 kilometres square area) through the use of  Threejs plugin to be able to export it in glTF.
By opening the DTM and the ortho on Threejs the ortho seems to be  in a lower resolution compared to the original file[image: loss of ortho quality in threejs] the ortho in threejs is less detailed with a lower number of pixel which results. I seek a way to  avoid this loss in quality